# Get the count of all found rows without using a subquery or sending an additional query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a subquery of my bigger main query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.item_id
 FROM pages_likes AS p1
   JOIN pages_likes AS p2 ON p1.item_id = p2.item_id AND p1.status = p2.status
 WHERE p1.uid = 855 AND p2.uid = 1091
 GROUP BY p1.id
```

This gives me this result for example:

`item_id`

`32`

`38`

`73`

So my expected count value I need to get is 3.

I need to know if I can get those found rows **without using subqueries** (not using an outer `SUM()`) and **without sending an additional mysql-query** (not using `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`).

This is because I can't place values/columns of the main columns inside a subquery-subquery which I need in my main query. So, is there any way that this query can count all the found rows with a single query?

My main query is this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT l1.item_id, l1.uid, l2.id, l2.uid, u.prename, l1.item_id, l2.item_id,
  (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT p1.item_id
    FROM pages_likes AS p1
      JOIN pages_likes AS p2 ON p1.item_id = p2.item_id AND p1.status = p2.status
    WHERE p1.uid = 855 AND p2.uid = 1091
    GROUP BY p1.id
  ) AS t) AS total

FROM pages_likes l1 
  JOIN users u on u.id = l1.uid 
  JOIN pages_likes l2 on l1.item_id = l2.item_id 
  JOIN users_likes ul on l1.uid = ul.uid 
WHERE ul.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
      AND l1.uid != 1091 AND l2.uid = 1091 
      AND (l1.status = 1 AND l2.status = 1) 
      AND u.gender = 2 
GROUP BY l1.uid 
ORDER BY 
  total DESC,
  l1.uid DESC, 
  l1.date DESC
```

My goal is to use `l1.uid` in my subquery of the main query instead of `855`.

Table structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1334

Comment: Any time you see DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query, you can be sure that something's wrong. Likewise, any time you see a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use this subquery:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.item_id)
 FROM pages_likes p1 JOIN
      pages_likes p2
      ON p1.item_id = p2.item_id AND p1.status = p2.status
 WHERE p1.uid = 855 AND p2.uid = 1091
)
```